# org-mode: List of all TODO entries is empty

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a number of agenda files with TODO keywords. Hitting <kbd>C-c-a-t</kbd> brings up an empty agenda. However, <kbd>C-c-a-T</kbd> then selecting TODO keyword does what is expected and shows all TODO items in the agenda.

Why does <kbd>C-c-a-t</kbd> not work as expected?

I use org-mode 8.2.9.

Comment: Both of these are supposed to call `org-todo-list` (without and with an argument resp.). Maybe `C-c a t` has been reboud somehow? I would put a breakpoint using edebug on `org-todo-list`, do `C-c a t` and see if it stops at the function. Or check with `C-h c C-c a` to make sure that's still a prefix key that's bound to `org-agenda` (if that is the case, then both t and T *should* work fine).

Comment: Actually 'org-todo-list' does what is expected. It seems that <kbd>t</kbd> in the agenda dispatcher is doing something else.

Comment: Just checked `org-agenda-custom-commands`, and I see that I have remapped `t` there.

Comment: I think I should delete this question, and will do so soon, unless anybody objects.

Comment: IMO, you should keep it: maybe post an answer and accept it, just to mark it done, but it is a common enough problem, so it might be helpful to future questioners.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see what the C-c a t binding is would be to call M-x describe-key (bound to C-h k).

Comment: This was the first thing I tried. I get this output:  C-c a runs the command org-agenda (found in global-map), which is an interactive
autoloaded Lisp function in ‘org-agenda.el’.

It is bound to \ a, <menu-bar> <Org> <Agenda Command...>, C-c a.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had copied my Org configuration from one machine to another and my username had changed, so check that the contents of the `org-agenda-files` variable is correct (which might point to an `org-files.txt` file containing a list of filenames.)